# Increase \label{} counter manually

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I use my own version of subsections for definitions:

```
\newcommand{\definition}[2]{\addtocounter{subsection}{1} \subsection*{\thesubsection ~ Definition (#1) \text{\normalfont{#2}}}}
```

I use them as:

```
\definition{DefinedThing}{\cite{Book}[Page 64]}
\label{def:DefinedThing}
```

This works great, the only problem I have is that the references do no longer work now:

```
\ref{def:DefinedThing}
```

This reference does only refer to the section in which the definition is used, not to the actual subsection it represents (for example it refers to "2" instead of to "2.5"). Is there a way to fix this? Maybe by increasing the counter for the \label{}.

Comment: use `\refstepcounter`

Comment: I tried it but I could not yet figure out if this works. If you have a working peace of code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Then you should start by posting a minimal example that compiles. Then it is a lot easier to help. BTW: what is that `\text` doing there? `\text` is for textual comments in displayed math, not for constructions like this.

Comment: Just replace `\addtocounter{subsection}{1}` by `\refstepcounter{subsection}` but better would be to use `\subsection` instead of `\subsection*`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The tip of David helped me. The sections are now displayed correctly.